# What tool generated this report of MySQL server performance?

Tags: mysql, database-administration

I found this report on the performance of a MySQL server. I would like to be able to generate this report for my own server, but I don't know what tool they used. Does anybody recognise this report?  What tool generates it?  How can I get that tool for my own use?

```
MySQL 5.1.55-rel12.6     uptime 150 12:36:47    Fri Dec 28 22:47:24 2012

__ Key _________________________________________________________________
Buffer used    48.23M of 128.00M  %Used:  37.68
  Current      34.21M            %Usage:  26.73
Write hit      51.99%
Read hit       99.23%

__ Questions ___________________________________________________________
Total           1.23G    94.9/s
  QC Hits     680.35M    52.3/s  %Total:  55.11
  DMS         291.77M    22.4/s           23.63
  Com_        228.64M    17.6/s           18.52
  COM_QUIT     41.30M     3.2/s            3.35
  -Unknown      7.42M     0.6/s            0.60
Slow          370.01k     0.0/s            0.03  %DMS:   0.13
DMS           291.77M    22.4/s           23.63
  SELECT      227.72M    17.5/s           18.44         78.05
  UPDATE       31.36M     2.4/s            2.54         10.75
  INSERT       24.80M     1.9/s            2.01          8.50
  DELETE        7.86M     0.6/s            0.64          2.69
  REPLACE      18.86k     0.0/s            0.00          0.01
Com_          228.64M    17.6/s           18.52
  set_option   88.38M     6.8/s            7.16
  change_db    60.14M     4.6/s            4.87
  show_fields  20.40M     1.6/s            1.65

__ SELECT and Sort _____________________________________________________
Scan           83.00M     6.4/s %SELECT:  36.45
Range          22.34M     1.7/s            9.81
Full join       1.80M     0.1/s            0.79
Range check   125.05k     0.0/s            0.05
Full rng join  88.66k     0.0/s            0.04
Sort scan      16.69M     1.3/s
Sort range     11.50M     0.9/s
Sort mrg pass 218.26k     0.0/s

__ Query Cache _________________________________________________________
Memory usage  200.85M of 256.00M  %Used:  78.46
Block Fragmnt  11.84%
Hits          680.35M    52.3/s
Inserts       185.39M    14.3/s
Insrt:Prune    2.80:1     9.2/s
Hit:Insert     3.67:1

__ Table Locks _________________________________________________________
Waited        746.00k     0.1/s  %Total:   0.23
Immediate     322.78M    24.8/s

__ Tables ______________________________________________________________
Open             1024 of 1024    %Cache: 100.00
Opened         35.78M     2.8/s

__ Connections _________________________________________________________
Max used          501 of  500      %Max: 100.20
Total          41.31M     3.2/s

__ Created Temp ________________________________________________________
Disk table     30.66M     2.4/s
Table          66.55M     5.1/s
File          434.52k     0.0/s

__ Threads _____________________________________________________________
Running             1 of    4
Cached             47 of   50      %Hit:  99.90
Created        41.94k     0.0/s
Slow                0       0/s

__ Aborted _____________________________________________________________
Clients        28.59k     0.0/s
Connects      721.20k     0.1/s

__ Bytes _______________________________________________________________
Sent           10.67T  820.4k/s
Received      258.58G   19.9k/s

__ InnoDB Buffer Pool __________________________________________________
Usage         383.97M of 383.98M  %Used: 100.00
Read ratio      0.004
Pages
  Free              1            %Total:   0.00
  Data         23.89k                     97.20 %Drty:   0.00
  Misc            688                      2.80
  Latched                                  0.00
Reads           3.58G   275.6/s
  From file    13.53M     1.0/s            0.38
  Ahead Rnd                 0/s
  Ahead Sql                 0/s
Writes        169.24M    13.0/s
Flushes         4.56M     0.4/s
Wait Free           0       0/s

__ InnoDB Lock _________________________________________________________
Waits            6522     0.0/s
Current             0
Time acquiring
  Total       8432082 ms
  Average        1292 ms
  Max          121611 ms

__ InnoDB Data, Pages, Rows ____________________________________________
Data
  Reads        13.74M     1.1/s
  Writes        7.41M     0.6/s
  fsync         3.10M     0.2/s
  Pending
    Reads           0
    Writes          0
    fsync           0

Pages
  Created     478.58k     0.0/s
  Read         22.11M     1.7/s
  Written       4.56M     0.4/s

Rows
  Deleted      10.34M     0.8/s
  Inserted     20.64M     1.6/s
  Read          2.50G   192.4/s
  Updated       1.61M     0.1/s
```

(Note: this question is a repost of [*How Do I get This Mysql Report in windows Server Can Any One Pls Help me Thanks in advance [closed]*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14079515/how-do-i-get-this-mysql-report-in-windows-server-can-any-one-pls-help-me-thanks) on StackOverflow. It's out of scope there, and poorly worded; but with revisions I think it's a good ServerFault question. I'm channeling the original poster, [VVL on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1936006/vvl).)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just confirmed that this output is in fact from the `mysqlreport` tool. It's available from the the following website, http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport, but I believe it to be available in most Linux repositories as a standard offering. It was available in the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL), for example, for **CentOS** and **Fedora** Linux distros.

`mysqlreport` is just a `Perl` script which makes connections to a MySQL DB and collects information such as `SHOW STATUS` and `SHOW GLOBAL STATUS` for example and then prints it out in a nicer format.

There are the following resources available:

- [live demo](http://hackmysql.com/live_mysqlreport)
- [Guide To Understanding mysqlreport](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreportguide)
- [mysqlreport Documentation](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreportdoc)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the output from [`mysqlreport`](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreport), a piece of code which makes the output from the [`SHOW STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/show-status.html) command easier to understand.

Here is [The Guide To Understanding `mysqlreport`](http://hackmysql.com/mysqlreportguide). It includes content like what you show in your question.

(Note: I first posted this answer to the original question at StackOverflow, but the question was closed as being out of scope. This answer follows the question in migrating to ServerFault.)

Comment: I just confirmed this on my CentOS 5.x system that mysqlreport is definitely the tool that was used to create that output.

Comment: @slm thanks for the confirmation. If you want, write a good full answer saying this, with links and all. I'll accept it as the answer to the original poster's question.